# Tcpdump on ec2 not seeing all packets

Tags: amazon-ec2, tcpdump, packet-capture, packets, packet-sniffer

I'm running tcpdump on an Amazon EC2 instance to monitor HTTP traffic going to Nginx  (this is just a test box, the only resource is the example test page).

Running tcpdump with the command

```
# tcpdump -vn -i any port 80
```

shows the packets from a browser's request to the site, but shows **nothing** when accessing the page using a Python script (using the Requests library) or with manually crafted packets (Scapy).

- There's no local firewall running and the Security groups are properly set up.
- The scripts work properly: I can capture the transactions in tcpdump on the local end easily enough, and they return the page with status 200 OK.
- Saving the packets directly to a file (-w) also makes no difference, ruling out buffering issues (I believe?)
- I've also tried seeing if [VLANs](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2012/08/misadventures-with-tcpdump-filters/) are causing the issue, but no luck; grepping for "80" still gives no results.

Questions:

1. What could be causing tcpdump to miss these quite specific packets that are **definitely** getting through the firewall to Nginx and back out again?
2. Why are packets from Firefox being seen whilst packets sent from the scripts slip by?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try using a specific interface instead of "any". That 'device' can't be used in promiscuous mode. See the tcpdump manpage: http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html

Comment: Doesn't seem to be it unfortunately; and I've no idea why that could capture only a subset of packets, rather than all or none?

Answer (score 1):

A technology that was released after this question was asked is [VPC Flow Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/flow-logs.html). This lets you look at network traffic in your VPC, filtered as you like.

VPC Flow Logs won't show you full packet contents, just basics like source, destination, port, protocol, size, time, and action like accept or reject, and a few others. It also won't show you traffic that originates and terminates inside an EC2 instance.

This isn't a direct answer to the question, as it doesn't solve the problem. It may however provide an alternate way to gather information to solve a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the `snaplength`?

> - -s snaplen
> - --snapshot-length=snaplen
>
> Snarf  snaplen  bytes  of  data from each packet rather than the default of 262144 bytes.  Packets truncated
>   because of a limited snapshot are indicated in the output with
>   ``[|proto]'', where proto is the name of the protocol level at which
>   the truncation has occurred.  *Note that taking larger snapshots both
>   increases the amount of  time  it takes  to  process packets and,
>   effectively, decreases the amount of packet buffering.  This may cause
>   packets to be lost.*  You should limit snaplen to the smallest number
>   that will capture the protocol information you're interested in. 
>   Setting snaplen to 0 sets it to the default of 262144, for backwards
>   compatibility with recent older versions of tcpdump.

I usually use 65535.